# Performance of MySQL NOW()

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I've started to dig deeper in the optimization of our database, thus scanning the web for all possible tips & tricks in this matter.

I've come across several articles mentioning the downsides of using `NOW()` in SELECTS due to disabling caching that particular query. Might be a dumb assumption since it's not cachable, but does this go for **INSERT/UPDATE** as well?

Put shortly, will using `NOW()` in my **INSERT/UPDATE-queries** affect performance in the same way it does to SELECT?

Comment: You answered your own question, didn't you?  It's not cached, so you most probably won't notice a difference.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of the non-caching part, but is that the only drawback of using NOW() in **SELECT** ? If so then I most certainly have the answer to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the current time, use `NOW()` or `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.  There are no drawbacks.

Caching is designed to "do the right thing".  It would be *wrong* to cache a `SELECT` with `NOW()` or `RAND()`, so it won't be cached.  I do *not* consider that to be a drawback.

`INSERTs` and `UPDATEs` cannot be cached.  Why would that every be of any use?

What we are talking about is the "Query cache".  The innodb_buffer_pool is another cache.  Again it "does the right thing".